# Deep classification, how to represent category as TF-IDF vector?

Tags: classification, text-mining, natural-language

I am trying to implement so called deep classification method described [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.141.805&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

I am trying to replicate chapter 4.2, with category-based search. Unfortunately, I am not sure how should I represent the category by one single tf-idf vector. (It is not clear for me from the paper).

What kind of representation would you suggest?

1. One big concatenated document (for whole category) and computation of the tf-idf for this document.
2. Computation of the tf-idf for each document separately separately and then computing average tf-idf vector.
3. Some other method?